# Read/write a large text/comments cell (6k+ chars) in Excel from/to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ssis, large-data

I am trying to alter an existing Excel 2010 workbook so that the data is hosted on MSSQL since the data is getting to large and the workbook too slow.  I'm using ADO.  My issue here is I don't know how best to handle the cells that contain a large amount of comments which also include carriage returns/line feeds and possible other special characters.  The largest cell contains approx 6000 characters so far.  I don't really expect the text within a given cell to get much bigger than that.

Questions: -

- What data type should I use within SQL Server to store this data?  I'm concerned about special characters like carriage returns.
- What is the best method to transfer data back and forth from Excel and MSSQL?  I could probably use a hidden ListObject to read the data, but I'm more concerned about writing any edits back.  The cell length is too long for a SQL string and I don't know how to handle the carriage returns.  I keep getting an Application Object error.  I don't have any problem with most cells and their data, just these large text cells that represent comment descriptions.
- I don't know how to handle the initial large data dump into MSSQL.  The SQL Server Import Wizard keeps failing stating there are characters not within the assigned code page.  There is no indication of the row it failed on or what characters are causing the issue.  Is that down to the data type I've chosen?  It is currently Varchar hence my first question.  Should I just use Text or NText?  Won't they make the database massive?  SSIS uses the import wizard so that will still fail.  Anything that requires a SQL statement such as ADO or OPENROWSET won't like the length of the data unless I'm missing something.

Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to store the data.  If there are carriage returns `CHAR(13)` or tabs `CHAR(9)` in your data, they can cause line breaks in Excel when you paste the data in.  I just `REPLACE()` them with a space character In order to bring data back in, look into the `BULK IMPORT` command.  Remember that you can make an SQL connection directly from Excel from the Data tab under Connections.

Comment: I would still need the line break.s  Users are writing paragraphs of information into 1 cell.  I will try NVarchar(max).  How will an Excek Data Connection help write back to MSSQL a cell that contains 6k+ characters?  The SQL in the command text won't like such a long string when writing INSERTs or UPDATEs and if it did I could simply carry in using ADO.